# AngularJS add variable to scope problems

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am working on a more complex project(10000+ LoC) and during development I encountered a problem very often.

When I add a simple variable to scope like:
$scope.editing = true;

```
   $sope.editing=false;

   $scope.changeTextButtonClicked = function() {
         $scope.editText;
   }
```

```html
   <span ng-hide="editing">{{editText}}</span>
   <input type="text" ng-model="editText" ng-show="editing">
   <input type ="button" ng-click="changeTextButtonClicked()">
```

The current value of `$scope.editText` can't be accessed from the controllers javascript code! 
In some cases I got the old value when accessing `$scope.editText` like the DOM is not updated but when printing it directly on the website with `{{editText}}` it works and gets updated but in the controller I get the old value.

It happened that I have one value for `{{editText}}` on the website and another value for `$scope.editText` in the controller (invalid one - previous).

I solved this with adding it to a data array or any other array that is nested inside the scope:

```
     $scope.data={}
     $scope.data.editText = ...;
```

Can anybody explain to me why it works sometimes with `$scope.variable` and sometime it doesn't and you need to add `$scope.**foobar**.variable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem time ago then i read this tutorial about scopes.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Anyway the main concept is that when you use ng-model always use a dot notation.
so $scope.user={}
and then $scope.user.name.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it finally. The problem is that the $watch can be only bound to an object and observe it and not to a elementary field like string, int . boolean & co.

The bad thing is when you have a object complex structure you cant only bind it to a property but rather to the whole object that causes performance issues if its a multilevel object.